# How to get flipkart product price via code?

Tags: java, android, api

I wanted to get the live price of the product on flipkart.com via code. Is there any way to get this.
I have tried alot to search for the api to fulfill this but failed.So please any one help me to get the answer of this..

Comment: let me also know when you get same :)

Comment: @KanakSony ... Do you have idea about it or have done any research on this topic. Please let me know yours.

Answer (score 0):

i have done research on that and Good News.. i have found some way.
There is a PHP API for flipkart price access..

See here: http://www.clusterdev.com/flipkart-api-demo/